# Cannot access a node js require from a parent scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

So here is how my code looks like :

```
const mod = require("./module.js")
let functionA = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         databasequery("sql", (response) => {
             databasequery("sql", (response) => {
                 console.log(mod)
             });
         });
    });
}
```

When I call this functionA, the console.log() prints `{}`, like if `mod` was an empty object.
But when I move the mod definition into the scope of the function like this :

```
let functionA = () => {
    const mod = require("./module.js")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         databasequery("sql", (response) => {
             databasequery("sql", (response) => {
                 console.log(mod)
             });
         });
    });
}
```

Suddenly, my console.log outputs me the expected object, with the functions I exported in my module.

Can anyone explain why changing the scope of the module suddenly makes everything work / break ?

Note : I don't set / create a `mod` variable ANYWHERE else in the code.

Note 2 : obviously, those aren't the real names of the function and module nor the real content, and my query functions look different too, but I tried to keep the hierarchy of callbacks and promises the same.

Note 3 : this is a cyclic / recursive require, but I don't see why would that be a problem.

Edit 1 : A few functions are exported from the required module. In my module source, the export looks like this :

```
module.exports = {
    "createInstance": createInstance,
    "getCurrentWebsocket": getCurrentWebsocket
};
```

Edit 2 : I reported a bug for nodejs https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

Edit 3 : module.js code :pastebin.com/QxmxDfhm

Comment: Can you show what is exported from module.js ? and how ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What do you get by printing `mod` directly in the module where `functionA` is defined ? (In your first example)

Comment: by adding a console.log(mod) right after it prints me an empty object. I very confused because putting a require in a different scope shouldn't change the contents of that require...

Comment: Also, I can't do the edit because it's less than 6 characters, but I guess the "equals" characters were not intended just after the second `databasequery` call.

Comment: The reason is most likely due to the behavior of arrow functions. If you are inside an arrow function that is nested by more than two levels (your first code excerpt) then, it cannot access the global scope. Moving require inside the first function actually makes it available. As a rule of thumb, better to avoid arrow function callbacks if they are more than two levels deep. Maybe consider refactoring your code.

Comment: the = characters are a typo on my question yes. But the arrow function thing doesn't explain why does it still outputs {} if I put a console.log in the global scope right after the require.

Comment: You're right, the external module cannot be aware of the scope from where it's required. But things could have changed in the global scope by the time `functionA` is called, and the module export could depend on global scope. That is why I asked you to show that module.

Comment: The global scope doesn't change, and for that weird behavior about arrow functions :

1 : I cannot find any documentation about this.

2 : If arrow functions that are nested by more than 2 levels cannot access objects from the global scope, why does it print {} instead of undefined or null ? Also, that still doesn't explain why is the require "aware" of what scope he is in.

Should I report a bug to node js ?

Comment: Do you confirm that there is nothing asynchronous happening while exporting from module.js ? Just a simple plain object ? Can you show the *actual* code of this module (exhaustively) ?

Comment: I confirm that nothing asynchronous happens while exporting from module.js. My module.js file is just a succession of lets of functions, values and other requires (that follow the same structure, nothing async happens during exportation for those as well).

Comment: Should I report a bug ?

Comment: I believe you, but since the export/require logic is part of the deep substance of NodeJS, I really doubt this is the source of your problem. I rather think some insidious mistake has been made in module.js, that's why I think you should post the whole code.

Comment: Talking about mistake, you indeed removed the equal character, but forgot to replace it with a parenthesis this time :)

Comment: I edited my post to add screenshots of my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213885/discussion-between-telno-and-julien-dargelos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got you a great explanation why this is happening. there is also a solution offer end of the article. Hope it helps. [article](https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js)